Part number of this IC marking "44t" - Identification
Please help me define the IC marking "44t" in the picture below.


Dimensions are important for identification questions. Both BAS40-04 and BAT54SW,115 have a 44* marking. One is SOT23 and the other SOT323. I'm pretty sure my answer is correct and this one is SOT323, but that's not really clear without dimensions.

Thank you very much

It's a Nexperia BAT54SW Schottky diode.


(Source: lcsc.com)
